# localhost HTTP Audio Webstreaming Software for Mac?

Tags: macos, streaming

I would like a make some sort of Apple Protocol HTTP Audio Stream that would be available to my local network.

So if I typed in "192.168.0.2" or "192.168.0.2:8080" on Mobile Safari it would recognize it as a webcast.

What software would do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

[VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) can be used for streaming and it supports HTTP. Here is the list of supported streaming [features](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html). You may follow some [guide](http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/).